# Placeholder names such as “John Doe” in French

Tags: informatique, société

Names such as “John Doe” (for males) and “Jane Doe” (for females) are used as placeholder names in the US and Canada when the identity of a person is unknown or must be withheld for some reason. Are there any such common placeholder names in French too?

Comment: I think "Monsieur/Madame X" (or some other initial if you want) would work.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  *Monsieur X* is used when you do not want to reveal the name of a person although you know their identity.

Comment: @Laure "or must be withheld for some reason"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we are looking for a placeholdername consisting on a [First Name + Name] basis the nearest equivalent of "John Doe" would be *Jean Dupont*, although the combination of *Jean+Dupont* is not as consistent in French as John+Doe is in English. Variations are found on first name (*Pierre* for example), or on name (*Durant* or Durand for example)

But the use of the equivalent of "John Doe" in French really depends on the context.

At the morgue and in legal matters in general a "John Doe" will be referred to as *inconnu* (*inconnue* in the case of an unidentified female).

In sociological studies and the press it is usual to designate a "John Doe" as *l'homme de la rue*.

In the press and in literature it is usual to come upon phrases such as
*Monsieur Toutlemonde*,  *Monsieur Dupont*, *[Tartempion](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tartempion)* (colloquial), ...

On  forms that have to be filled in (administration, online forms...) we sometimes find *Dupont* or *Jean Dupont*.

For reference on the Royal Bank of Canada Website :
"[Here lies the mind of John Doe](http://www.rbc.com/aboutus/letter/december1974.html)" →  "*[Ci-gît l'intelligence de Monsieur Dupont](http://www.rbc.com/aproposderbc/bulletin/decembre1974.html)*".

When females then *Madame Toutlemonde, Madame Dupont, Marie Dupont, la femme de la rue...*

Comment: What about French speaking populations of Canada? Do they follow the US conventions and use 'John Doe' or stick to the French versions of 'Jean' and 'Dupont'?

Comment: @user3182445 Sorry I'd forgotten to link to the RBC, done now. It seems John Doe is not used in Quebec. Although I expect you will find lots of John Does wrongly translated into John Doe in French texts because those who translate do not understand what they are talking about; as the [Linguee data base](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=John+Doe) shows. But as I say *Jean Dupont* is just one of the first name+name combination. Others could be found with *Pierre* and *Jean* being probably most common as first name, and Dupont or Durand as name.

Comment: [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=JOHN+DOE) (the government of Canada's terminology and linguistic data bank) suggests that federal translators should use Pierre Untel for John Doe.

Comment: _La femme de la rue_ ou bien _la ménagère de moins de cinquante ans_.

Comment: I'd had "l'individu/la personne lambda" to this list, especially in the press

Comment: Jean DuponD, bien sûr ! =)

Comment: **Madame Michu** is missing!

Answer (score 5):

M. **Untel** & Mme. **Untelle**

from french.about.com [Tel Telle Tels Telles](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/tel.htm)

Comment: *M.Untel*, would not be used in most cases. *M. Untel* is as restricted in its usage as would be "Mr so-and-so" or "whatsisname".

Answer (score 0):

When seeking this information in the past I came upon a Wikipedia page with an interesting breakdown and was unfortunately the most substantial I could find at the time, especially since my knowledge of French is abysmal despite trying to write a piece featuring French characters in late 19th/ very early 20th century.

As others mentioned, it really depends on what you are using the placeholder for:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language#French

I'm sure I don't have to say this is merely a good jumping-off point and not definitive information. Hope this helps.